# Память выделяется с ошибкой

Tags: память, c++

Выделяется память под массив

```
double** Beta = new double*[_p];
for(int i = 0; i < _p; i++) {
    Beta[i] = new double[_q];
}
```

При _q <= 6 прога работает нормально, стоит задать значение _q больше, вылетает ошибка:

```
*** glibc detected *** /media/win_d/ProgramFiles/projects/TSP_lab2-3/TSP_lab2-3: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x08d32818 ***
```

В чем тут может быть проблема?

Переместил выделение памяти немного раньше, начала вылетать та же ошибка, но при выделении памяти под другой массив (которое теперь происходит после выделение под Beta) в том же методе.

Код метода до перемещения:

```
TMovingAverage::TMovingAverage(double *_Phi, double *_C, int _p, int _q, double _Eps)
{
    p = _p;
    q = _q;

    steps = 0;

    Eps = _Eps;

    Phi = new double[p+1];
    Phi[0] = -1.0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        Phi[i] = _Phi[i-1];
    }

    C = new double[p+q+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= p+q; i++) {
        C[i] = _C[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= p+q; i++)
        cout << C[i] << " ";

    Cstroke = calculateCstroke();

    Beta = new double*[_p];
    for(int i = 0; i < _p; i++) {
        Beta[i] = new double[_q];
    }

    Beta[0][0] = -1.0;
    cout << Beta[0][0] << " ";
    for(int i = 1; i <= _q; i++) {
        Beta[0][i] = 0.0;
        cout << Beta[0][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Код метода после перемещения:

```
TMovingAverage::TMovingAverage(double *_Phi, double *_C, int _p, int _q, double _Eps)
{
    p = _p;
    q = _q;

    Beta = new double*[_p];
    for(int i = 0; i < _p; i++) {
        Beta[i] = new double[_q];
    }

    Beta[0][0] = -1.0;
    cout << Beta[0][0] << " ";
    for(int i = 1; i <= _q; i++) {
        Theta[0][i] = 0.0;
        cout << Beta[0][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    steps = 0;

    Eps = _Eps;

    Phi = new double[p+1];
    Phi[0] = -1.0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        Phi[i] = _Phi[i-1];
    }

    C = new double[p+q+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= p+q; i++) {
        C[i] = _C[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= p+q; i++)
        cout << C[i] << " ";

    Cstroke = calculateCstroke();
}
```

Comment: Theta здесь не видна, но используется, так и задумано?

    Theta[0][i] = 0.0;

Comment: не правильно суда скопировал, не Theta а Beta

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на логику delete в коде до вызова этого метода. Особенно на delete в циклах. 

Такие ошибки часто бывают, когда одну и ту же память освобождают несколько раз.

Comment: Вы можете легко проверить, находится проблема в выделении памяти под `Beta` или нет, изолировав этот код в тестовое приложение. Вообще, я бы рекомендовал удалить как можно больше кусков из программы до тех пор, пока можно и креш воспроизводится. Попытайтесь сделать минимальный пример, который воспроизводит проблему. В подавляющем большинстве случаев ошибка становится самоочевидна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Beta[i] = new double[_q];
...
for(int i = 1; i <= _q; i++) {
        Beta[0][i] = 0.0;
```

здесь происходит выход за границы массива, надо i<_q либо _q+1 в new

Comment: >здесь происходит выход за границы массива

+1

>надо i<_q либо _q+1 в new

Или Beta[0][i - 1] в цикле. Организация циклов в принципе не очевидная. Лучше так не писать, по крайней мере, на этапе разработки программы.

Comment: @MorkOFF48, а ведь код до перемещения вылетал наверное при втором вызове (или третьем), а Вы про это не сказали.

Comment: @MorkOFF48, если проблем с памятью нет, значит @sercxjo решил Вашу проблему, это стоит отметить.

Answer (score 3):

> В чем тут может быть проблема?

Проблема в Вашем коде, который работает с какой-то памятью, выделенной в этой же куче. `Memory corruption` не может быть определена непосредственно в момент повреждения памяти, поэтому первое же обращение к куче, **после ошибки** приводит к такому исключению.

Смотрите логику программы "выше по коду", там и ошибка.

Банально можно "разрушить кучу", записав данные за пределами выделенного блока памяти.

> Он подменяет большое кол-во разных функций, в том числе выделения/освобождения памяти. Потому и может контролировать процесс. Конечно, это сказывается на производительности.

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), такие методы позволяют выявить только следствия проблемы, а не причину.

Причина выявляется с помощью сканирования операций обращения к памяти. Т.е., сканер периодически останавливает исследуемую программу и смотрит ее контекст операций. Если находит команду записи или чтения за пределы выделенного региона памяти, сигнализирует пользователю.

Такие сканеры оч. дороги в обоих смыслах, т.к. если находят ошибку, то именно в том месте, где она происходит. И, соответственно, чем чаще она исследует испытуемую, тем больше вероятность найти ошибку и дольше процесс исследования, а это - время.

К тому же, не все ошибки памяти можно повторить на таком "слайд-шоу". Поэтому **потребность в человеческой логике при поиске таких ошибок будет еще весьма надолго**.

Comment: Изменил описание вопроса, выше. Вроде все делается нормально...

Comment: Если здесь нет ошибки, смотрите еще "выше". Выше - не в смысле выше полистингу, а **выше по стеку вызовов**, т.е. раньше.

Comment: А может тогда "электрическую ограду" (electric-fence)? Хотя, судя по начальной букве T у автора винды, что не может не усложнить задачу.

Comment: >А может тогда "электрическую ограду" (electric-fence)?

Принцип тот же. Только он точного места ошибки не найдет. Найдет в каком-то диапазоне (между остановками испытуемой), уменьшение которого так же будет стоить времени, увеличение которого, в свою очередь, может уменьшать вероятность возникновения ошибки. Масло масляное, но - суть.

Answer (score 3):

Так как у Вас линукс, запустите код под valgrind. Он скорее всего подскажет, где искать.

**Как valgrind узнает о проблемах?**

Он подменяет большое кол-во разных функций, в том числе выделения/освобождения памяти. Потому и может контролировать процесс. Конечно, это сказывается на производительности.

**где его взять**

В репозиториях большинства дистрибутивов есть. Точно есть в fedora, ubuntu/debian.

**Как использовать**

- компилируем с параметрами `-ggdb -g3` (это что бы по максимуму включить разной отладочной информации).
- запускаем первый проход `valgrind -v ./your_app -your_app_param`
- смотрим в вывод. Там обычно есть указание, на что смотреть. А также могут быть подсказки, с какими параметрами перезапустить, что бы увидеть больше вывода. (например, для отслеживания утечек  - `--leak-check=full`)

**Как компилятор помогает узнать повреждения памяти в массивах?**

Одна с популярных технологий. Памяти под массивы выделяется на несколько байт больше (обычно на один-два элемента). В эти дополнительные ячейки записываются специальные байты. Время от времени (но обычно перед освобождением) вставляются проверки, а не поменялись ли ключевые байты. Если они поменялись - тревога.

Comment: Ответил в своем ответе (не хватило места).

Comment: почитал Ваше дополнение. Я не писал, что в результате будет точное место и как именно исправить. Я написал слово "подсказки". А вот их анализ - это уже человеческая работа.
Остальная часть Вашего дополнения - поток сознания.

Comment: >Я не писал, что в результате будет точное место и как именно исправить

Я понимаю, но при первом прочтении у меня сложилось впечатление, что все проблемы решит `valgrind`. Поэтому и прокомментировал, чтобы не было заблуждений.

Comment: Это исключительно Ваше понимание.

любой инструмент в опытных руках творит чудеса. Но даже самый совершенный инструмент в непонимающих руках ничего не даст.